# Is Michael Scofield imitating someone when he utters the phrase "The ocean is your frontyard"?

Tags: dialogue, prison-break

In *Prison Break* S04E04, titled "Eagles and Angels", Michael and Sara are talking just outside the  depot in the shipyard. Michael utters the phrase "The ocean is your frontyard" with a voice other than his typical which led me to think he may be imitating someone.

There is a reference to SS Minnow in that dialogue, which makes Gilliang's Island a likely candidate.

What is the (TV) origin of the phrase "The Ocean is Your Frontyard"?

Comment: I think that voice is one way that he tries to ease up Sara from her burden, try to minimize the tension and something different than their usual life. something new, exciting and don't forget they are lovers who didn't get much time for be themselves. so it could be a way that Michael tries to build up something towards that. hope for new life, more specifically , a normal life. a house with pretty view, fun and hope